# What does וְיַמְלִיךְ מַלְכוּתֵהּ in Kaddish mean?

Tags: tefilla, kaddish

There are some versions that have it with "Vikarev Mishichei" following the "Viyamlich Malchuse", and that seems to mean that the Kaddish is a prayer for Moshiach(?)

myJewishLearning.com it has without the Moshiach part, as follows:

> יִתְגַּדַּל וְיִתְקַדַּשׁ שְׁמֵהּ רַבָּא. בְּעָלְמָא דִּי בְרָא
>   כִרְעוּתֵהּ **וְיַמְלִיךְ מַלְכוּתֵהּ** בְּחַיֵּיכון וּבְיומֵיכון
>   וּבְחַיֵּי דְכָל בֵּית יִשרָאֵל **בַּעֲגָלָא וּבִזְמַן קָרִיב**,
>   וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן

Translation:
*May He establish His kingdom in your lifetime and during your days,
and within the life of the entire House of Israel, **speedily and soon**;
and say, Amen.*

What is this kingdom that we are asking for to be established?

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=CMfXcg9Au7IC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=hashem+future+kingdom&source=bl&ots=9WaE9kYB0Z&sig=ACfU3U3ZepiEXy1Q6htpKSeQ1o_aIYSiqw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE75CtyuXoAhXImOAKHbb1DLAQ6AEwCnoECAoQKQ#v=onepage&q=hashem%20future%20kingdom&f=false  http://www.kby.org.il/english/torat-yavneh/view.asp?id=3613

Comment: @rosends thanks, but those two links don't specifically mention kaddish, although if you want to infer from those sources to here, then it seems to imply that that it's a reference to when Moshiach comes then God's kingdom will be established throughout the world(?)

Comment: @rosends the Google books link I just checked the page you sent the link to I didn't check the whole book though, I'll search it more though

Comment: Why would we think that there are two different concepts of a heavenly kingdom on earth? We say "Yimloch Hashem le'olam...", we say "Hashem yimloch le'olam va'ed" and other things straight through davening and refer to Hashem as a king, past, present and future.

Comment: @rosends in the kby.org.il link: "...In the future, however, G-d's kingdom will extend even over the nations, ..." That does sound like the times of Moshiach.

Comment: so is your question "why do some version of kaddish omit the explicit reference to Mashiach?"

Comment: @rosends No. I'm trying to understand what "_May he establish his kingdom_..." means.  "Yimloch Hashem le'olam...", and "Hashem yimloch le'olam va'ed" is just a prayer/blessing that it is / should be forever, implying that his kingdom is already established. וְיַמְלִיךְ מַלְכוּתֵהּ sounds like it has not been established yet.

Comment: @rosends consider בַּעֲגָלָא וּבִזְמַן קָרִיב. that sounds like it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: the end of Az Yashir indicates that though Hashem rules now and forever, there will be a difference in the nature of the ruling over the world in the future, and this is the kingdom which we yearn for. I see all the future statements like "Hashem yimloch" as aspirations not towards the continuation of the same de facto "God rules over all" but the change to "al kol ha'aretz" in a messianic era.

Comment: @rosends So the Kaddish prayer is about Moshiach?

Comment: that's why I'm wondering if your question shouldn't be "why do some versions seem to make it seem NOT about Moshiach by taking out v'yatzmach...?"

Comment: https://www.jewishlinknj.com/features/26579-v-yatzmach-purkanei-v-kareiv-mishichei https://www.kayj.net/forum/nusach/1171-kaddish-veyatzmach-purkonei-why-not-in-nusach-ashkenaz?lang=he

Comment: @rosends but even with just  וְיַמְלִיךְ מַלְכוּתֵהּ and בַּעֲגָלָא וּבִזְמַן קָרִיב, what other explanations can there be, besides that it's referencing to moshiach?

Comment: I don't think that there ARE any other explanations. The text makes it pretty clear that, in conjunction with other prayers. the mention refers to a messianic age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aruch HaShulchan Orach Chaim 56:2 explains this phrase as a prayer for the arrival of the future in which G-d’s Kingdom will be recognized over the entire world (as prophesied in Zechariah 14:9) i.e. the Messianic Age.